# how to display a selected column in PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am running this query in PHP:

```
$sql="SELECT t.* FROM tickets t join 
(select ticketnumber, max(datetime) as maxdt from ticket_updates tu GROUP BY ticketnumber) tu

ON t.ticketnumber = tu.ticketnumber

WHERE t.status <> 'Completed' AND tu.maxdt < now() - interval 1 hour; ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    echo $result["tu.maxdt"];
}
```

but its not showing the `datetime` column

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Try `echo $result['maxdt']`

Comment: You need to include it in the select.

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got to include this column in your query:

```
$sql="SELECT t.*, tu.* FROM tickets t join 
(select ticketnumber, max(datetime) as maxdt from ticket_updates tu GROUP BY ticketnumber) tu

ON t.ticketnumber = tu.ticketnumber

WHERE t.status <> 'Completed' AND tu.maxdt < now() - interval 1 hour; ";
```

Answer (score 0):

The column is called `maxdt` not `tu.maxdt` so it needs to be `echo $result['maxdt']`.  You also need to include the column in your `select` statement:

```
SELECT t.*, tu.* 
FROM tickets t join 
(SELECT ticketnumber, max(datetime) AS maxdt 
 FROM ticket_updates tu 
 GROUP BY ticketnumber) tu 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you are selecting `max(datetime) as maxdt` in a sub select. This won't come out as  `tu.maxtd` and it needs to be included in the main select

```
SELECT t.*, max(tu.datetime) as maxdt FROM tickets

echo $result["maxdt"];
```

As an aside **mysql_** functions are deprecated, you should switch to **mysqli_**. https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation